# Why are my dynamically added ListViews to a LinearLayout not displaying properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am dynamically adding `ListView` layouts to my vertically oriented `LinearLayout`. However, when the app runs, all of the data are squished together on the screen. If I try to scroll, I find that each independent `ListView` is scrollable, and I only see one line at a time per `ListView`, instead of my enclosing `LinearLayout` being scrollable.

Here is what I have:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView();

        printSensors();
    }

    private void printSensors(){
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        ListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        for(Sensor sensor : sensorList){
            ListView listView = new ListView(this);
            listView.setId(View.generateViewId());
            listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            String[] sensorArray = sensor.toString().substring(1, sensor.toString().length()-1).split(",");
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensorArray);

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            mainLayout.addView(listView);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_layout" android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

However, if I change `ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` to an integer, say `500`, then everything lays out nicely and looks good.

So, what gives?

Answer (score 0):

change width of your listView to match parent instead of wrap content, also you have to set height and width to scroll view

Comment: The width of the ListViews **is** set to `MATCH_PARENT`. Plus, what do you mean by "also you have to set height and width to scroll view"?

Comment: can you explain why you add list view dynamically and not set it in you layout? if you add listView in main Layout and set adapter to it, I think it may work well

Comment: I am adding a `ListView` per sensor type. As I can't know the number of sensors before the app is run (due to each device being different), I need to add them dynamically.

Comment: you can define listView in your layout, and define ArrayList in MainActivity, fill it in your for loop, and after for loop set adapter with this arrayList to your listView.. like

Comment: What you have suggested will have each succeeding sensor output overwrite the one before.

Comment: Adding items to arrayList doesn't overwrite it's data.. just try the code in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private void printSensors(){
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<String> sensorArray = new ArrayList<>();
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    for(Sensor sensor : sensorList){
        sensorArray.add(sensor.toString().substring(1, sensor.toString().length()-1).split(",").toString());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensorArray);
    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I tried it this way ... it doesn't work. All that gets printed out is the resource ID for each sensor, and it's still squished together.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the LinearLayout in another LinearLayout as follows:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/main_layout"
     android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Didn't work ... I still end up with a bunch of vertically-stacked scrollable `ListView` views where I can only see the first line. I set both width and height to `MATCH_PARENT` for both `LinearLayout` views. I also tried `WRAP_CONTENT` for the `main_view` `LinearLayout`.